# linkify text to send email?

Tags: android, linkify

I am trying to make a clickable text using linkify. When the name is clicked on, I want to call email intent. However, the email address is not the same as the linkify. Is there any way through linkify to do a mailto:specificname@gmail.com when you have the pattern be "Specific Name"? Here is my example code:

```
final TextView tx1=new TextView(this);
tx1.setAutoLinkMask(0);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("John Doe");
Linkify.addLinks(tx1, pattern, "mailto:johndoe@gmail.com");
```

As you can see here, this issue is that the email intent fills in for the subject: "johndoe@gmail.comJohn Doe". This is an obvious result, but I don't know how to truncate the pattern text in the scheme.... Thanks for your help.

ps if you know of an alternative way not involving linkify, you get credit as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a non-Linkify answer:

```
 final TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
 String name = "John Doe";
 String email = "johndoe@gmail.com";

 tx1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:"+email+"\">"+name+"</a>"));
 tx1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

but there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: I had considered this but am not crazy about hardcoding the text... It's a long string

Answer (score 0):

You can use TransformFilter for this case.
[Linkify TransformFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.TransformFilter.html)